# Real technical advantages of React Native over Web

Tags: react-native

I thinking about real technical advantages of creating React Native app over web SPA. I figured out that only 1 advantage could be - it's saving and loading data in phone store. Another things like, for example, access to GPS, camera, etc are also available in JavaScript Web. So, that is real technical advantage of using React Native over Web?

Answer (score 1):

*Overall, it really depends on what your application is for...*

If your Application will be used by mobile users only, then React Native is a perfect solution. However, if you want an application with a Web presence, so users can use it on Desktops etc - then it wouldn't really be suitable unless you did both a Web SPA and a mobile app.

For example, if I were to create an accounting app - which will be used by users on Mobiles and Desktop, then perhaps I'd consider building a SPA which is mobile friendly or both SPA and an App with an API for both.

If you were building a tracking app, which will only be available for mobile - then go for it.

If your users will be using desktop, then you can build it perhaps in React and when you get to React Native you know the react library!

React Native in itself builds both iOS and Android Apps, so instead of creating a 'hybrid' app (which includes webviews) or a native App in both iOS and Android - you only create one code base and build it to your chosen OS. This saves alot of development time. As the community is open source, alot of upgrades happen and there is alot of help online if you encounter an issue.

Comment: Thank you, for answer! But I understand all of this, because I know React and React Native. There are web SPA on React and React Native app. My question is,  is there technical advantages of React Native app or no, instead of working in offline?