# React for a Web Development Over Alternative

Tags: java, reactjs

Can someone explain why is React so popular?

- My understanding is that it helps with the V part of MVC design pattern for apps and is useful as its JS so can be used for UI perhaps in general.

Why would it be better than SPA (not sure I get what this means exactly, i.e. just using Javascript? - [Real technical advantages of React Native over Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407947/real-technical-advantages-of-react-native-over-web))

- Also, it was created by Facebook so perhaps there is added benefit/functionality through that (if anyone can provide specifics that would help.

But what are the specific technical advantages/efficiencies about React is so advantageous and helpful to developers?

**As an example, say I work for a bank and am designing a bank account app - how would React be useful over an alternative?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it basically depends upon what type of application you are making . Few benefits that I found with react are:

1. It is based on the concept of virtual dom (main benefit of it): you can read more abt it from https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html
2. Easy to learn as mostly it is javascript, ES6 compared to Angular latest versions
3. Good community support

However, React alone is of no good use for big applications. So ultimately you have to use some state management tool like redux/ flux with it

Comment: +1 big support with other libraries such as the well-known Bootstrap, offers to build platform apps, android/ios app with react native, desktops apps, web apps, easy to get started, simply great one, and the fact that there's "good" company holding it :) and more, personally, i like it even more than angular. (just for me). it just good and simple, and trust me, i do like angular, but react the number 1 for me. and i actually learned angular at first place, and when i started to learn react, i just like it more/ but again just me :)

Comment: Can you give an example or idea of what you'd use Redux for?